# Multivariate curve fit in python

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

Can somebody please point me in the right direction...

I need to find the parameters a,b,c,d of two functions:

*Y1 = ( (**a** * X1 + **b**) * p0  + (**c** * X2 + **d**) * p1 )  /  (**a** * X1 + **b**  +  **c** * X2 + **d**)*

*Y2 = ( (**a** * X2 + **b**) * p2  + (**c** * X2 + **d**) * p3 )  /  (**a** * X1 + **b**  +  **c** * X2 + **d**)*

X1, X2 (independent variables) and Y1, Y2 (dependent variables) are observations, i.e. one-dimensional arrays with thousands of entries each.

p0, p1, p2, p3 are known constants (scalars).

I successfully solved the problem with the first function only with a curve-fit (see below), but how do i solve the problem for Y1 and Y2 ?

Thank you.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


X  = [X1,X2]

def fitFunc(X, a,b,c,d):
    X1, X2 = X
    return ((a * X1 + b) * p0  + (c * X2 + d) * p1) / (a * X1 + b + c * X2 + d)

fitPar, fitCov = curve_fit(fitFunc, X, Y1)

print(fitPar)
```

Comment: Define another fit function, now with your formula for Y2 and do the same as you have done previously, changing Y1 to Y2 in your curve_fit.

Comment: Thank you, but this way i would get different solutions for a,b,c and d for each of the two functions. I should have mentioned, that both functions have be fulfilled at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to minimize both your functions together using `scipy.optimize.minimze`. In the example below, a function `residual` is passed `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` as initial guesses. Using these guesses, `Y1` and `Y2` are evaluated, then the mean squared error is taken using the data and predicted values of respective functions. The error is returned as the mean error of the two functions. The optimized set of parameters is stored in `res` as `res.x`.

```python
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

#p0 = ... known
#p1 = ... known
#p2 = ... known
#p3 = ... known

def Y1(X, a,b,c,d):
    X1, X2 = X
    return ((a * X1 + b) * p0  + (c * X2 + d) * p1) / (a * X1 + b + c * X2 + d)

def Y2(X, a,b,c,d):
    X1, X2 = X
    return ((a * X1 + b) * p2  + (c * X2 + d) * p3) / (a * X1 + b + c * X2 + d)

X1 = np.array([X1]) # your X1 array
X2 = np.array([X2]) # your X2 array
X = np.array([X1, X2])
y1_data = np.array([y1_data]) # your y1 data
y2_data = np.array([y2_data]) # your y2 data

def residual(x):
    a = x[0]
    b = x[1]
    c = x[2]
    d = x[3]
    y1_pred = Y1(X,a,b,c,d)
    y2_pred = Y2(X,a,b,c,d)
    err1 = np.mean((y1_data - y1_pred)**2)
    err2 = np.mean((y2_data - y2_pred)**2)
    error = (err1 + err2) / 2
    return error

x0 = [1, 1, 1, 1] # Initial guess for a, b, c, and d respectively
res = minimize(residual, x0, method="Nelder-Mead")  
print(res.x)
```

Comment: Isn't it a bit overkill to use `sklearn` for a function that's trivial to write in numpy (`np.mean((y1_data-y1_pred)**2)`)?

Comment: I actually thought at first to write it in NumPy. I have incorporated it now!

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Unfortunately the result is not as beautiful as I expected :-)

Comment: Maybe you need a better initial guess? Also try to use some options like `fatol`. Try: `res = minimize(residual, x0, method="Nelder-Mead", options={'fatol': 1e-04})`. But I guess the initial guess needs to be good in order to get an optimal set of parameters.